# SQLAlchemy add child to an already existing parent: KeyError

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, relationship, parent-child

I have looked through similar questions on stackoverflow but found no working solution for my particular case. I suspect the problem is on the stage of creating a parent class as I create it without `my_cards`, but I have no idea how to create it with it because it's a relationship field. I have a one-to many relationship in `database_models.py`:

```
class UserBase(Base):

""" An account for storing and accessing multiple learning cards """

__tablename__ = 'users'

id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
telegram_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), unique=True)
name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(200))
surname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(200))
my_cards: Mapped[list['AssociationClass']] = relationship()


class CardBase(Base):

""" A learning card with front and back text bound to a specific user """

__tablename__ = 'cards'

id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
name = mapped_column(Text)
front = mapped_column(Text)
back = mapped_column(Text)


class AssociationClass(Base):



__tablename__ = 'association_table'

user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
card_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('cards.id'), primary_key=True)
card: Mapped['CardBase'] = relationship()
```

However, when I try to execute the following:

```
async def add_child_to_db(
query,
child,
my_async_session: AsyncSession):

""" Adds a child class to parent class """

async with my_async_session.begin() as session:
    try:
        parent = await session.execute(query)
        parent = parent.first()
        a = AssociationClass()
        a.card = child
        print(f'\n\n\n\n{a.card}\n\n\n\n')
        await parent.my_cards.append(a)
    except SQLAlchemyError as exc:
        print(exc)
        raise
    finally:
        await session.close()
```

The session rolls back. I receive the KeyError. The traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/bots/bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 202, in _key_not_found
    self._key_fallback(key, None)
  File "/home/user/bots/bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 141, in _key_fallback
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'my_cards'
```

I either do not understand the syntax or have created the database wrongly. Any help is appreciated. Ready to provide additional details on request.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that you need a class instance to add item to database with relationships. `parent.first()` is not suitable and you have to use `scalar_one()`:

`database_models.py`

```
class UserBase(Base):

""" An account for storing and accessing multiple learning cards """

__tablename__ = 'users'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
telegram_id = Column(String, unique=True)
username = Column(String(100), unique=True)
name = Column(String(200))
surname = Column(String(200))
my_cards: Mapped[Optional['CardBase']] = relationship(back_populates='my_user')


class CardBase(Base):

""" A learning card with front and back text bound to a specific user """

__tablename__ = 'cards'

id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('users.telegram_id'))
my_user: Mapped['UserBase'] = relationship(back_populates='my_cards')
name = mapped_column(Text)
front = mapped_column(Text)
back = mapped_column(Text)
```

`database_append_card.py`:

```
    query = select(UserBase).where(UserBase.telegram_id == str(message.from_user.id))
    current_user = await retrieve_data_from_db(query, async_session_maker)
    current_user = current_user.scalar_one()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        new_card = CardBase(
            name=data['card_name'],
            front=data['front'],
            back=data['back'],
            user_id=current_user.telegram_id)
    await add_item_to_db(new_card, async_session_maker)
```